# Windows 7 Logo Program for Software Test Cases, where are they?

Tags: windows-7

There lots of info about for the hardware testing, but nothing for software. All I can find is a PDF with the 'requirements' and 'policies' ([http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=27028822-b172-4cec-91a3-26b610a4da79]).

Certification for vista involved a whole load of test cases.

I'd like to get my hands on them if anyone has any info.

Comment: It might be still too early, but you can bet they'll be very similar to the testing/logo requirements for Vista

Comment: I think Microsoft had announced that Vista drivers work for Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an alpha version (as of late April) from here:
  https://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=831

Best wishes,

Tim